# Google ChatBot - TextInput fields required

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-chat

I'm developing a chatbot using Google App Scripts and I was wondering how to get a textInputs field required/ mandatory. For example, I have a dialog Box with an input text (as reported below) and i would like to get this field mandatory to fill in for the user.
How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

```
{....
 "textInput": {
                      "label": "Name",
                      "type": "SINGLE_LINE",
                      "name": "contactName"
                    }
....}
```

This is the entire Dialog Box with different text input fields and I would like get them required to fill in for the user.

```
return {
    "action_response": {
      "type": "DIALOG",
      "dialog_action": {
        "dialog": {
          "body": {
            "sections": [
              {
                "header": "Add new contact",
                "widgets": [
                  {
                    "textInput": {
                      "label": "Name",
                      "type": "SINGLE_LINE",
                      "name": "contactName"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "textInput": {
                      "label": "Address",
                      "type": "MULTIPLE_LINE",
                      "name": "address"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "decoratedText": {
                      "text": "Add to favorites",
                      "switchControl": {
                        "controlType": "SWITCH",
                        "name": "saveFavorite"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "decoratedText": {
                      "text": "Merge with existing contacts",
                      "switchControl": {
                        "controlType": "SWITCH",
                        "name": "mergeContact",
                        "selected": true
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "buttonList": {
                      "buttons": [
                        {
                          "text": "Next",
                          "onClick": {
                            "action": {
                              "function": "openSequentialDialog"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: `"required": true` ?

Comment: @Kosh unfortunately I've already tried but it doesn't work. Thks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google chat doesn't have that feature, because there is no submit event like HTML submit form does. Only `onClick` event. So you should add your own validation on the button onClick event script.

Based on your code maybe you can do with like below:

```
const formValues = event.common?.formInputs;
const contactName = formValues?.['contactName']?.stringInputs.value[0]?.trim();
if(!contactName) {
return buildContactForm(event); // this is your own contact form builder
}
```

Currently, I also creating google chat apps that have validation, you can check my example validation [here](https://github.com/dyaskur/google-chat-poll/blob/master/index.js#L94). So I returned the form again if the the required field  doesn't inputted.

Comment: Im trying to implement validation for my input fields also, can you point to some valid link where i can see in your project how you are doing it? The link that you have provided up isnt working anymore. Thanks in advance.